# JSONP + ASP.NET - Response is incomplete

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, jsonp

We have been wrestling with the confines of ASP.NET trying to get JSONP working. We're trying to check whether a file exists on a different server and return a boolean value. The function is called on jquery's ready() function, so it should happened after all DOM elements are loaded.

We've used the HTTPModule request/response rewriter linked here:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/ASPNET_JSONP.aspx

The AJAX call:

```
function CheckFileExists() {
    var _FileID = $('#FileID').val();
    var button = $('#btnViewFiles');
    button.val('Checking...').css('color', '');
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",            
        url: localAdminUrl + "WebServices.asmx/CheckFileExists",
        data: { FileID: _FileID },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {            
            if (data.d == true) {
                button.attr('onClick', 'ViewFiles(_FileID,false);').removeAttr('disabled').val('View documents').css('color', '#22CA00');
            } else {
                button.val('No documents').css('color', '#DD3BB3').removeAttr('onClick').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            button.val('Error occurred').css('color', '#DD3BB3').removeAttr('onClick').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }            
    });
}
```

Now, for some reason the response *occasionally* decides to omit the end parentheses and semicolon, leaving an incomplete response, and JSON crying "parsererror".

example:

```
jQuery<numbers>_<numbers>({"d":false}
```

instead of the expected:

```
jQuery<numbers>_<numbers>({"d":false});
```

The baffling thing is that it only happens occasionally - some requests end up complete and parse correctly. What on earth is going on?

I've tried rewriting the HTTPModule such that the response is written once instead of three times:

```
public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        var b1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_context.Request.Params["callback"] + "(");
        var b2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(");");
        byte[] finalResponse = new byte[b1.Length + buffer.Length + b2.Length];

        b1.CopyTo(finalResponse,0);
        buffer.CopyTo(finalResponse, b1.Length);
        b2.CopyTo(finalResponse, b1.Length + buffer.Length);
        _responseStream.Write(finalResponse, 0, finalResponse.Length);
        /* Old way
        _responseStream.Write(b1, 0, b1.Length);
        _responseStream.Write(buffer, offset, count);
        var b2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(");");
        _responseStream.Write(b2, 0, b2.Length);
        */
}
```

Doesn't seem to have helped though.

Comment: Looks like `_responseStream` is not being flushed/disposed. Hard to say for sure without looking at the code that calls `Write()`

Comment: Can you put more code in regarding `_responseStream`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the GZIPStream compression module which we use is buggy, see here: [GZipStream And DeflateStream will not decompress all bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271260/gzipstream-and-deflatestream-will-not-decompress-all-bytes)

We've removed the module from use for the time being and the responses are now being returned consistently complete.