# Gzipped content doesn't reflect input

Tags: c#, gzip

I have a very simple gzip method:

```
    public byte[] Compress(string input)
    {
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);

        using (var msi = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        using (var mso = new MemoryStream())
        using (var gz = new GZipStream(mso, CompressionMode.Compress))
        {
            msi.CopyTo(gz);

            return mso.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

However, unit tests fail. Even passing in a simple short string doesn't get gzipp'ed properly. e.g. `"this is a test"` becomes a byte array with 10 elements: `[31,139,8,0,0,0,0,0,4,0]` which of course doesn't ungzip properly. What's going wrong here? This has come straight from msdn!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GZipStream And DeflateStream will not decompress all bytes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271260/gzipstream-and-deflatestream-will-not-decompress-all-bytes)

Answer (score 1):

You need to <s>flush</s> close the stream for it to compress. At the point you call `mso.ToArray()`, the `GZipStream` hasn't compressed anything yet and is waiting for more data.

A simple solution:

```
public byte[] Compress(string input)
{
    var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);

    using (var msi = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    using (var mso = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var gz = new GZipStream(mso, CompressionMode.Compress))
        {
            msi.CopyTo(gz);
        }

        return mso.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, that sure is a gotcha! Thanks